# How do I declare a object for use with this function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function which is declared as:

```
bool getIndex(const QString itemUid, QModelIndex& index /*out*/);
```

how do I declare an object to pass in as index?

I have tried:

```
QModelIndex *modelIndex;
getIndex(auid, modelIndex  );
```

with and without the "*", but I get compile errors.

The compilation error is:

> no matching function for call to TreeModel::getIndex(QString, QModelIndex*&)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Argument Passing "passed by reference"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827119/c-argument-passing-passed-by-reference)

Comment: `QModeIndex modeIndex;`

Comment: What is your compilation error?

Comment: @101010 He said he tried it with and without the "*", which I assume refers that exact answer.

Comment: It's hard to believe that *without* "*" gave you compilation errors. What exactly were the errors?

Comment: @RedRoboHood fingers crossed.

Comment: Your error function signature does not match the function signature you posted.  Please edit your question to contain an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: OK - my mistake, without the "*" works.  There was an error in the first parameter, too.  Thanks for your help. { red faced }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling without the * shouldn't give you errors (assuming you are not doing something like `QModelIndex *modelIndex();`).

Another way to solve your problem would be to declare your function like so :

```
bool getIndex(const QString itemUid, QModelIndex* index /*out*/);
```

And then create your object as a reference like before:

```
QModelIndex *modelIndex;
getIndex(auid, modelIndex);
```

The downside to this though is that you'd have to change the function everywhere you use `index` to instead treat it like a pointer rather than reference.
I find it more likely that your error may lie elsewhere in your code, and be the nature of the `QModelIndex` object.

Answer (score -3):

The requested argument is `QModelIndex&`, so you can just call

```
QModelIndex modelIndex();
getIndex(auid, modelIndex);
```

Btw: QModelIndex is a really slim object which gets invalid very quickly. You should not create pointers to it without deep insight to Qt's Model/View system.

Comment: No you can't.  `QModelIndex modelIndex();` wont compile as it fails the most vexing parse.

Comment: Well, then `QModelIndex modelIndex;`. `getIndex(auid, QModelIndex())` is better anyway.