# C++ Carrying user input from one function to another and displaying it with main(newbie)

Tags: c++, function

trying to take user input with `getinput` function,transfer it to `vaidornot` function and display if else loop to screen with main method but i couldnt. How can i do that ? also there is a problem with double variable ? :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getinput(string restname, string name, double point) {
    cout << name << "please enter the name of restaurant: " << endl;
    cin >> restname;
    cout << name << "please enter the scores of" << restname << "for first level evolution" << endl;
    cin >> point;
}

void validornot(double point) {
    if (point > 5) {
        cout << "point is bigger than 5" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "point is smaller than 5" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    string name;
    string restname;
    double point;

    cout << "Welcome to my restaurant rating programme.Please enter your name to start:" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Welcome " << name << endl;
    getinput(restname, name, point);
    validornot(point);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] and format your code

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *references*.

Comment: Do you know what passing by value and passing by reference are?  If not read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827119/c-argument-passing-passed-by-reference

Answer (score 1):

You can change `void getinput(string restname,string name, double point)`
to

```
void getinput(string restname,string name, double& point)
```

Comment: thanks its all done