# Not able to find out the error while implementing QuickSort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am writing a basic QuickSort method, but I am unable to find out the errors in the code. The program is returning the same input as after going through the sorting function.Although I cross-checked my code with other internet resources, I tried to find out the error myself, and there seems to be some error in the Partition function, but I'm not able to figure out what exactly is causing the error.

Below is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void swap(int n1, int n2)
{
    int temp = n1;
    n1=n2;
    n2=temp;

}



int Partition(vector<int> &A, int start, int end)
{
        int pivot = A[end];
        int Pindex = start;
        for(int i=start;i<end;i++)
        {
            if(A[i]<=pivot)
            {
                swap(A[i],A[Pindex]);
                Pindex++;
            }
        }
        swap(A[Pindex],A[end]);
        return Pindex;
}

void QuickSort(vector<int> &A, int start, int end)
{
    if(start<end)
    {
        int Pindex = Partition(A,start,end);
      //  printf("Partition Index:%d  \n",Pindex);
        QuickSort(A,start,Pindex-1);
        QuickSort(A,Pindex+1,end);
    }
}





int main()
{
    vector<int>A = {4,6,7,9,3,2,0,5};
    cout<<"Before Sorting\n";
    int length = A.size();
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",A[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
    QuickSort(A,0,length-1);
    cout<<"After Sorting:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",A[i]);


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: thats cos your swap function doesnt do anyting. It is simply juggling local copies of its input numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(int * n1, int * n2) 
{ int temp = *n1; *n1=*n2; *n2=temp; }
```

swap must be reference by address and not valid value. Or the values will be not to exchanged.

Also while calling swap function call it as follows `swap(&A[i] , &A[j])`

Answer (score 1):

If you code that way in Java, you also hit the same problem. The root cause is that the value you compared in the `swap` funtion is passed into that function **by value**, compared with **by reference**. 
Refer to this link: [C++: Argument Passing "passed by reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827119/c-argument-passing-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is , you sending two integer variable in `swap(int a,int b)` function.
This variables exchange value between them.

But you have an array which holds this `integer` values.  you need to pass the array to swap two `integer` basis of their position.

You need to call `swap` function in following way :

```
void swap(vector<int> &A,int Pindex,int end){                                                  
    int temp = A[Pindex]; 
    A[Pindex]= A[end];
    A[end]=temp; 
}
```