# Can I set a value using a function in a class?

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

If I have a `friend` function can I somehow use `set()` to assign a value to a private variable inside the function? Or some other method?

Example : Here I have 3 `private` variables. I tried to make the sum of 2 of them and store the result in the 3rd one. I tried to do it with a setter but the result is 0. In main it works, but I don't know if I can make it work in the class function.

```
#include <iostream>
using  namespace std;

class Function{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;

public:
    Function() = default;
    Function(int _a, int _b);
    friend int sumNumber(Function f);
    
    //Setter and getter
    int getA() const;
    void setA(int a);
    int getB() const;
    void setB(int b);
    int getSum() const;
    void setSum(int sum);
};

Function::Function(int _a, int _b) {
    this->a = _a;
    this->b = _b;
}
int Function::getA() const {
    return a;
}
void Function::setA(int a) {
    Function::a = a;
}
int Function::getB() const {
    return b;
}
void Function::setB(int b) {
    Function::b = b;
}
int Function::getSum() const {
    return sum;
}
void Function::setSum(int sum) {
    Function::sum = sum;
}



int sumNumber(Function f) {
    int a = f.getA();
    int b = f.getB();
    int sum = a + b;
    f.setSum(sum);
    return sum;
};



int main() {
Function AA(1,2);
cout << sumNumber(AA);
cout << " " << AA.getSum();

AA.setSum(sumNumber(AA));
cout << "\n" << AA.getSum();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
3 0
3
```

Comment: `int sumNumber(Function f)` receives a **copy** of the `Function` passed to it.  Changing that copy does not change the original.  It's time to check your C++ book for "[pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827119/c-argument-passing-passed-by-reference/19827270)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, the issue is with this function:

```
int sumNumber(Function f) {
    int a = f.getA();
    int b = f.getB();
    int sum = a + b;
    f.setSum(sum);
    return sum;
};
```

---

Let us walk through your code:

`Function AA(1,2);`

You create a object of type `Function`, called `AA` and you allocate each member variable of that object via the constructor (`1` and `2`).

`cout << sumNumber(AA);`

You call your method (`sumNumber`) and pass to it **a copy** of your variable `AA`. That function adds the two numbers together and internally calls `setSum`.

`cout << " " << AA.getSum();`

You now try to display the `sum` value by calling the `getSum` method. But the issue was that you passed **a copy of your variable** into the `sumNumber` function. The original `AA` variable was left alone.

---

To fix this you need to adjust your function by adding an ampersand `&`. Like this:

```
int sumNumber(Function& f) {
    int a = f.getA();
    int b = f.getB();
    int sum = a + b;
    f.setSum(sum);
    return sum;
};
```

Now your variable `AA` is being passed **by reference** and not **by value**. There are lots of [tutorials](https://www.journaldev.com/38174/pass-by-reference-c-plus-plus#:%7E:text=The%20method%20to%20pass%20by%20reference%20in%20C%2B%2B,using%20any%20of%20the%20variable%20or%20reference%20name.) about this concept.